# Java: How to I know if a String has one of the ENUM present?

Tags: java

```
public enum OPERATORS {
  MUL("*"), ADD("+"), SUB("-"), DIV("/")
}
```

and a String as

```
s = A2 B4 * C5 /
```

How can I check if `s` has one of the `OPERATORS`?

Comment: Show us the rest of the `enum` declaration.  In particular, the getter for the attribute that holds the enum's string value.

Comment: Do you only want to check if `s` *contains* one of the `OPERATORS`? Or do you want to parse the String as a postfix mathematical expression?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming getOperatorSymbol() is implemented in your enum

```
for (OPERATORS op: OPERATORS.values()) {
  if(s.contains(op.getOperatorSymbol())
  {
      //your code
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check if s has one of the OPERATORS?

You have to code it somehow.  The strings you are searching for are not the names of the `enum` value.  They are stored in a custom attribute.  So you have to manually extract the strings and then search in the target string for each one.

There are multiple of ways you could do this; e.g.

- You could simply loop over the OPERATOR enum values, extract each one's operator string and test it against your input string; see @pangea's Answer.
- You could use the loop to build a regex that would match any of the operator strings and then use that regex to match the string.  This would be a good approach if performance is a real concern and you can amortize the cost of creating the regex; i.e. do it just once, and reuse the regex multiple times.  (But if performance is not a concern, the extra complexity of this approach is not warranted.)